# How to write g or G number from C to C++ using cout?

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I want to write this (last line) but by using cout.

```
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
        if (b < 0)
            sign1 = '-';
        else 
            sign1 = '+';
        if (c < 0)
            sign2 = '-';
        else 
            sign2 = '+';
        b = fabs(b);
        c = fabs(c);
        printf("%g*x^2 %c %g*x %c %g \n", a, sign1, b, sign2, c);
```

Is this correct? I think scientific is not equal %g or %G in C. Also is that true printf("%c", a) is equal to cout << a, so default is char and I need to add in cout anything to print something as char?

```
cout << a << scientific << "*x^2 " << sign1 << " " << b << scientific << "*x " << sign2 << " " << c << scientific << endl;
```

Comment: If I'm reading [the documention](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) correctly, then `std::cout << c` without any extra modifiers does exactly that. It prints floating point number without scientific notation if its exponent is small and with scientific notation if needed.

Comment: thanks you're right, so just "out << a << "*x^2 " << sign1 << " " << b  << "*x " << sign2 << " " << c << endl;"

Answer (score 1):

`scientific` should go first. i.e. `cout << scientific << variable`.